# Twentieth-century emigration from Romania?

Tags: england, 20th-century, immigration, romania, emigration

My Grandfather arrived in England round about 1910 and married my Grandmother in 1912.  His surname was Cancea and we believe his first name was Stanley.
We have one family letter which looks like he came from Bucherest but would be interested to know how I go about finding more out about his family and why he left Romania?

---

I have also found out that my Grandma had to change her nationality from British to Romanian to marry my Grandfather in 1912. Why would this have been?

Comment: Hi, Sarah -- welcome to G&FH.SE! I see you've taken the [tour], but we also encourage new users to read the material in the [help], starting with [What topics can I ask about here?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).  If you need more information about how the site works, you can ask in our companion area [meta]. I've edited your question title so there is an actual question in it. Hope you enjoy exploring the site!

Comment: While you're waiting for an answer, take a look at some of the questions already on the site tagged [tag:Romania].

Answer (score 3):

In the 1911 UK census he is called Stan, which is indeed possibly a shortened version of Stanley. He was a 26 year old boarder at 19 Blissett Street, Greenwich, and his occupation was Engineer. His birthplace is recorded as Buakaw or Buakan (difficult to read due to a correction on the form) in Rumania. As the form was filled out by the homeowner, he might not have understood or written down the name of the town properly.
Good luck in your research

Comment: According to http://www.behindthename.com/name/stan-2 "Stan" is a Romanian given name, probably derived from Stanislav (which itself was not used by Romanians). The birthplace may be Bacău, which is in Moldavia, in the east of Romania.